# Android to Zigbee communication

Tags: android, project, zigbee

I am a college student doing a project on connecting an Android app to a light switch, I am wondering if  using Zigbee communications is appropriate.

Comment: Hello, you need a Zigbee-enabled device, and I am not sure if Android can handle this. Zigbee is similiar to Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect to the hardware via an [Arduino+board](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWirelessShield) and then relay the messages to the Android device or even install Android on the Arduino and work from there?

Answer (score 1):

There is not many ( if any ) android devices with build in zigbee. You Would need an adapter like this: http://ligi-tec.blogspot.de/2009/02/dubwise-range-extender.html
But perhaps step back before and think why you want zigbee for your use-case. Do you need the range? Do you want the mesh-capabilities ( if this is your reason you might need more than the above adapter). IMHO you should stick to wifi or blutooth for switching lights